# Unable to make a if-else loop for google-books in Bash

Tags: bash

**My current code**

```
#!/bin/bash

#w=$2
#e=$3
#r=$4
#t=$5
#o=$5
#
prepend=""
append=""
case "$1" in
    -h)
        echo 'Usage: google [-{hxdw}] [<arg>]'
        echo '       -h: show help.'
        echo '       -x: search for "<arg> is"'
        echo '       -d: search for "define:<arg>"'
        echo '       -w: search for <arg> site:wikipedia.org'
        exit;;

    -x)
        prepend="\""
        append=" is\""
        shift;;
    -d)
        prepend="\"define:"
        append="\""
        shift;;
    -w)
        prepend=""
        append=" site:.wikipedia.org"
        shift;;
    -wo)
        prepend=""
        append=" site:.mathworld.wolfram.com/"
        shift;;
    -so)
        prepend=""
        append=" site:.stackoverflow.com/"
        shift;;
    -b)
        prepend=""
        append=""
        shift;;



esac
if [[ -z "$1" ]] ; then      # I am not sure about this line and about -z 
    query=""
else
    query="?q=${prepend}${1}${append}${params}"
fi
# you can use echo to put the url to history, eg
# echo http://www.google.com/search${query}

open "http://www.google.com/search${query}"
```

I want an if-else loop for the open command such that

**My unsuccessful attempt**

```
if $1==-b; then$
     open "http://www.books.google.com/search${query}"
 else
     open "http://www.google.com/search${query}"                               
 fi
```

I get by executing the shell script with gg

```
gg -b "Freakonomics"        
line 54: Freakonomics==-b: command not found
```

**How can you check the value of $1** such that you can start a google-books-search in Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
if [ "$1" = "-b" ]; then
    open "http://www.books.google.com/search${query}"
else
    open "http://www.google.com/search${query}"                               
fi
```

**Edit:** Added spaces before and after the comparison operator, thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)'s comment.

Comment: You need spaces around that equal sign or it'll always evaluate as true. Unless you need compatibility with sh, you should always use double brackets in bash: if [[ "$1" == "-b" ]]; then

Comment: The code is now the following: http://dpaste.com/59761/ . I run % gg -b "Freakonomics". I get a default google search. --- Do you know what can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

eleven81 has it right. Take a look at the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for more info on comparisons.